# Strip Punctuation From String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, strip, punctuation

I`m working with documents, and I need to have the words isolated without punctuation. I know how to use string.split(" ") to make each word just the letters, but the punctuation baffles me.

Comment: you can use regex to match the word

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example using regex, and the result is 
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'punctuation']

```
s = " ,this ?is a string! with punctuation. "
import re
pattern = re.compile('\w+')
result = pattern.findall(s)
print(result)
```